# Operator = override c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to override my = operator. I have 2 pointer parent they need to be pointers.

p1* and p2*

this is my override inside parent

```
Parent Parent::operator=(const Parent& otherParent) const
    {
        return Parent(otherParent);
    }
```

And here is my copy constructor:

```
Parent::Parent(const Parent& otherParent) : myChild("") {
    this->name = otherParent.GetParentName();
    myChild = Child(otherParent.GetChild());
}
```

And this is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Child c1 = Child("rupert");
    Parent* p1 = new Parent("Parent1", c1);
    cout << *p1 << endl;

    Child c2 = Child("bob");
    Parent* p3 = new Parent("Parent3", c2);
    cout << *p3 << endl;

    *p3 = *p1; 
    cout << *p3 << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
```

}

Why does it print out this:

Parent name: Parent1 Child name: rupert

Parent name: Parent3 Child name: bob

Parent name: Parent3 Child name: bob

The third print should be the same as the first.

Comment: editted wasnt using the copy constructor but the constructor but the issue remains.

Comment: Your assignment operator does nothing. It ignores its left operand and returns a copy of its right operand.

Comment: melpomene is right, and besides the assignment operator is supposed to return reference.

Comment: `operator=` should contain logic to update the current object.  Your code does not attempt to update the current object, which is why you get the same output for `*p3` before and after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the assignment statement `*p3 = *p1` as working like this:

```
p3->operator=(*p1);
```

That is valid syntax. If you look at it like that, you should be able to see that the assignment operator needs to modify `this` if it is actually going to do any assigning. Right now you create and return a temporary that is immediately destructed.

Comment: `Parent& Parent::operator=(const Parent& otherParent) 
{
 this->name = otherParent.GetParentName();
 this->myChild = otherParent.GetChild();
 return *this;
}`